# Azure Data Factory - Exists transformation in Data Flow with generic dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having issues using the Exists Transformation within a Data Flow with a generic dataset.

I have two sources (one from staging table "sourceStg", one from DWH table "sourceDwh") and want to compare if the UniqueIdentifier-Column in the staging table is existing in the UniqueIdentifier-Column in the DWH table. For that I have a generic data set which I query with a SQL statement containing parameters.

When I open the "Exists settings" I cannot choose any Column from the source in the conditions since the source is generic and has no Projection until I run the data flow. However, I have a parameter which I get from the parent pipeline which provides me the name of the Column containing the UniqueIdentifier (both column names in staging / DWH are the same).

I tried to add following statement "byName($UniqueIdentifier)" in the left and right column field but the engine resolves them both as the sourceStg-Column since the prefix of the source-transformations is missing and it defaults to the first one. What I basically now try to achieve is having some statement as followed defining the correct source-transformation and the column containing the unique identifier with a parameter.

`exists(sourceStg@$UniqueIdentifier == sourceDwh@$UniqueIdentifier)`

But either the expression cannot be parsed or the result does not retrieve the actual UniqueIdentifier value from the column but writes the statement (e.g. sourceStg@$UniqueIdentifier) as column value.

The only workaround I found so far is having two derived columns which adds a suffix to the UniqueIdentifier-Column in one source and a new parameter $UniqueIdentiferDwh which is populate with the parameter $UniqueIdentifier and the same suffix as used in the derived column.

Any Azure Data Factory experts out there to help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: byName($UniqueIdentifier,sourceStg) == byName($UniqueIdentifier,sourceDwh) as the custom expression in your Exists

Comment: This is not working. I tried to enclose the source name with ' ' which allows me to save. For the left column I get the correct data previews. For the right column, I get NULL as data preview and the number of rows is equal to the sourceStg but not the sourceDwh. So it seems it still tries to resolve the sourceStg-source but can't find the column.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the quotes: byName($UniqueIdentifier,'sourceStg') == byName($UniqueIdentifier,'sourceDwh'). Are you using this in an Exists transformation? How many rows are in each source?

Comment: Strange. When I check the visual expression builder previews for each column, it shows me for the sourceStg column the correct 9 UniqueIdentifiers. For the sourceDwh column it shows me 9 NULL rows. However, when I check the datapreview of the Exists transformation having type "doesn't exist", I can see only on row as 8 out of 9 UniqueIdentifiers are existing in sourceDwh. So the end result is correct and only the data preview of the expression builder is corrupt. Thank you!!

Comment: Data preview is a "best effort" to allow you to peak into the data frames. You can try a higher limit to rows in "debug settings" to get more matches, or use a sample file for your source to ensure that you always see matches when eyeballing in data preview mode.